# Seeking road network of Sweden with speed limits

Tags: data, road, sweden

I need road network data of Sweden with the speed limit of each segment of the road. I downloaded it from https://download.geofabrik.de/ but unfortunately, there are a lot of missing values there.

Is there any other website to get this data from free?

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Have a search: https://www.geodata.se/geodataportalen/srv/swe/catalog.search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roads with speed limits (hastighetsgrans) are available at Trafikverket:

https://lastkajen.trafikverket.se/107_OA_FileStorage/Default.aspx

[image]